# How to replace IN in an SQL query containing a lot of parameters with Postgresql?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I am trying to retrieve information from a database using a Python tuple containing a set of ids (between 1000 and 10000 ids), but my query uses the `IN` statement and is subsequently very slow.

```
query = """ SELECT * 
            FROM table1
            LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
            LEFT JOIN ..
            LEFT JOIN ...
            WHERE table1.id IN {} """.format(my_tuple)
```

and then I query the database using PostgreSQL to charge the result in a Pandas dataframe:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tmpfile:
            copy_sql = "COPY ({query}) TO STDOUT WITH CSV {head}".format(
               query=query, head="HEADER"
            )
            conn = db_engine.raw_connection()
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.copy_expert(copy_sql, tmpfile)
            tmpfile.seek(0)
            df = pd.read_csv(tmpfile, low_memory=False)
```

I know that `IN` is not very efficient with a high number of parameters, but I do not have any idea to optimise this part of the query. Any hint?

Comment: HINT: use `EXISTS`

Comment: Insert tuple of IDs into a separate temp table then join to your query. Increase performance by using IDs as indexes.

Comment: The IN list is not slow by magic.  It can sometimes make the planner choose the wrong plan, but the details of this depend on the version you are running.  You should EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) your query and see what it is doing.  For all you/we know it is already optimal, and it just unavoidably takes a long time to do a lot of work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I would like to go for @Parfait's solution: `COPY` value list to a temp table, index it, and then `JOIN` on the temp table. The next thing I miss is how to load my Python tuple in a temporary Postgreql table!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could debug your query using [explain statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html). Probably you are trying to 
sequently read big table while needing only a few rows. Is field table1.id indexed?

Or you could try to filter table1 first and then start joining

```
with t1 as (
 select f1,f2, .... from table1 where id in {}
)
select *
from t1
 left join ....
```